# Set System Properties in JSF+Spring Application

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I am developing a web application using JSF 2.0 ,Spring 3.1.

When I am deploying my application I am getting following error

```
ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'AllProjectDetailsBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springApp-spring.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'OutputFilePath'
```

Application Context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    </bean>

    <bean id="AllProjectDetailsBean"
        class="com.tcs.srl.expertFinder.sections.ProjectDetailsBeanFactory"
        factory-method="createInstance">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${OutputFilePath}" />
    </bean>
```

What I understand from error is when I deploy application the context loads very first time but it fails because it dose not find any property with name **OutputFilePath**. 
That means I have to set system property with the name **OutputFilePath** before context loads.

Can some tell me how to set system property while deploying jsf application or before context loads.

Or is there any option to remove this error.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: I suppose `ProjectDetailsBeanFactory` is your own implementation class. You can replace `${OutputFilePath}` by an String, it'll work. Otherwise, there are several forms to set that property without harcoding it (using Maven properties, external configuration files..)

Comment: What application server are you running?